# How to add value in list

Tags: reactjs, list

I have a function for aliment my list :

```
      buildListMenu = () =>{
    {dashboardRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
      if(prop.subMenus != null){
        const menu = {
          code: prop.code,
          openSubMenu: false
        };
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          listMenu: [...prevState.listMenu, menu] 
        }));
      }
    })}
    console.log(this.state.listMenu);
  }
```

Le problème c'est qu'au moment du console.log ma liste est vide. Sa taille est de 0.

Comment: prevState.listMenu.concat(menu) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      listMenu: [...prevState.listMenu, menu] 
    }), () => console.log(this.state.listMenu));
```

By origin, `this.setState()` will take some time to do the changes, in this case, when your `console.log()` is fired, it will be printing the current state, not the new one that is coming in a while.

What I did, is using the second parameter that `this.setState()` could have, which is a callback function that gets revoked once the state has been replaced, in this case, it's the `console.log()` function.

if that one failed to print your update on the state let me know